# MIPS - is there a way to transfer the value of the flag in coprocessor 1 to integer registers of coprocessor 0?

Tags: assembly, floating-point, comparison, mips, spim

I'm making a compiler for a school project and I am using MIPS assembly as my target code. But that's not important. I know that operations involving floating-point numbers are done in coprocessor 1 and that result of comparison instructions like `c.eq.d` and `c.le.d` are in the flag that can be tested through `bc1t` and `bc1f`. Is there a way that the MIPS can transfer the value of the flag to coprocessor 0's registers (e.g. `$a0`) without using the branching instruction of `bc1t` and `bc1f`. If this is impossible, how can I create anonymous labels in SPIM? It seems like SPIM doesn't support this feature. (Pls correct me if i'm wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `MOVF` (or `MOVT`) to put a value in a GPR based on a single FP condition code:

```
MOVF rd, rs, cc

To test an FP condition code then conditionally move a GPR

If the floating point condition code specified by CC is zero, then the contents of GPR rs are placed into GPR rd.
```

---

Or, if you want all the condition codes at once you could use `CFC1`:

```
CFC1 rt, fs

Copy the 32-bit word from FP (coprocessor 1) control register fs into GPR rt.

if fs = 0 then
    temp <- FIR
elseif fs = 25 then
    temp <- 0^24 || FCSR31..25 || FCSR23
elseif fs = 26 then
    temp <- 0^14 || FCSR17..12 || 0^5 || FCSR6..2 || 0^2
elseif fs = 28 then
    temp <- 0^20 || FCSR11.7 || 0^4 || FCSR24 || FCSR1..0
elseif fs = 31 then
    temp <- FCSR
else
    temp <- UNPREDICTABLE
endif
GPR[rt] <- temp
```

The bits you want are 23 and 25..31, so either `$f25` or `$f31` should be appropriate to use as `fs`.

Comment: I'm new to MIPS so i can't fully understand your answer but I think the second one works. Thanks.